# How to solve this second-order nonlinear ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to solve:

$$
\ddot{x} + \frac{1}{2} \dot{x}^2 - n e^{-2x} ~ e^{c t} - 2 e^{-2t} =0,
$$
where c and n are constants. I'm  trying to find x as a function of t.

**My trial**

I started by letting: $x= log ~r \to e^{-2x} =r^{-2}$, then, $ x’ = \frac{r’}{r}, ~~~ x’’ = \frac{r’’}{r}- \frac{r’^2}{r^2}$, substitute, we get:

$$
\frac{\ddot{r}}{r} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\dot{r}^2}{r^2} - n r^{-2} e^{ct} -2 e^{-2t} =0
$$

Any help on how to complete from here or from the original equation?

Comment: Where is the question coming from? Not sure that you'll be able to get a solution in terms of known functions.

Comment: Taking $x=2\log(z)$ brings your equation to a Yermakov 'look-a-like' equation: $z''-e^{-2t}z=ne^{ct}/(2z^3)$. Perhaps someone can extend the known solutions beyond the general form $y''+f(x)y=g(x)'/y-g(x)^2/y^3$ to encompass your problem?